# Not able to use the latest version of Python Library Six

Tags: python, pip

I have just installed the newest version of python library six using pip, which is 1.10.0. However when I try to print out the version in ipython, using six.version, I get "1.5.2". You can also see that in the images below as well.

[image: pip version]

[image: 1.5.2 version]

Comment: But you didn't pass the option for upgrading. Try `sudo -H pip install -U six`.

Comment: Probably you're using the wrong `pip` for your `ipython`. What is your `ipython`'s output if you run `import sys ; print ("\n".join(sys.path))`?

Comment: Argl, why are you pip-installing into the system's Python environment?

Comment: @Oli The `sudo pip` malpractice is unfortunately very common. :(

Answer (score 3):

## Don't do that! *Please* don't use `sudo pip`!

You're trying to overwrite something in the system's Python environment. If you ensist on using that environment for whatever it is you're doing, use the packages `python-six` and/or `python3-six`.

Why? Because Ubuntu depends on Python for many, many things. Replacing a system library with a new version  could mean you break vast amounts of the system. The packaged, Ubuntu-distributed versions are tested against each other.

If you want Six 1.10, you have a few options:

1. Upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 which ships 1.10.
2. [Use a virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). This creates a local environment and you can have whatever versions of whatever Python packages you like. It uses the system Python binary (and that is optional) but nothing else.
3. Better than either one of those, do both. If you're on Python 3, you'll get access to a load of lovely 3.5 stuff (mmm async) and if you're not, then it's just a slightly later version of 2.7.